# MySQL not working after upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, mysql

After a good deal of troubleshooting I have managed to get Plasma running however MySQL will still not start

```
systemctl status mysql.service
â mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2016-05-26 15:43:35 CDT; 36s ago
  Process: 18735 ExecStartPost=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 18734 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 18946 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 18734 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 26 15:43:34 Stark.newbierpg.com systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
May 26 15:43:34 Stark.newbierpg.com systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 26 15:43:34 Stark.newbierpg.com systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 26 15:43:35 Stark.newbierpg.com systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
May 26 15:43:35 Stark.newbierpg.com systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
May 26 15:43:35 Stark.newbierpg.com systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
May 26 15:43:35 Stark.newbierpg.com systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
root@Stark:/etc# service mysql start
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
root@Stark:/etc# systemctl status mysql.service
â mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (start-post) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2016-05-26 15:47:30 CDT; 3s ago
  Process: 20207 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 20205 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 20207 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE);         : 20208 (mysql-systemd-s)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           ââcontrol
             ââ20208 /bin/bash /usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post
             ââ20245 sleep 1

May 26 15:47:30 Stark.newbierpg.com systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
May 26 15:47:33 Stark.newbierpg.com systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

we were also facing same issue after Upgarde from 14.04 to 16.04
Solved the problem by removing

```
myisam-recover = BACKUP
```

and

```
key_buffer = 16M
```

from `my.cnf`.

Then use

```
sudo service mysql start
```

to start the MySQL daemon again and

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

to recover your system packaging state.

I found this advicehere: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.7/+bug/1570673, you can check also

Comment: My my.cnf had to copies of the key_buffer = 16M line.  I had to kill both of them.

Comment: Sidenote: You don't need to kill your key_buffer entries, just rename them to key_buffer_size as the former is now deprecated in newer MySQL versions.

Comment: i dont have multiple my.cnf files with different sizes but when i open them they are all empty. if i try to re-install mysql i get
E: mysql-server-5.7: subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
E: mysql-server: dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

Comment: I had this as well on a fresh 16.04! On MariaDB 10.0 this.

Answer (score 4):

I can't rate or comment, but in a fresh install of Ubuntu I used below then reinstalled and worked fine!

```
apt-get purge mysql-*
rm -fr /var/lib/mysql*
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution.  However, I doubt the OP did not think about it, neither what your answer adds to existing ones (of which one is accepted).

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this message when trying to start or restart mysql

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

and when using

```
systemctl status mysql.service
```

I get this message

```
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server <br>
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)<br>
   Active: activating (start-post) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2016-11-10 17:09:58 AST; 24s ago<br>
Process: 31363 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld **(code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)**
Process: 31360 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre **(code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)**<br>
Main PID: 31363 **(code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)**;         : 31364 (mysql-systemd-s)<br>
CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service<br>
       └─control<br>
         ├─31364 /bin/bash /usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post
         └─31441 sleep 1<br>
```

The problem was because of issues in the file `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`. You can troubleshoot using `mysql` - it will show you where the error is like this :

```
mysql: [ERROR] Found option without preceding group in config file /etc/mysql/my.cnf at **line 20**!
mysql: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
```

The you can try to solve it by commenting out (be inserting `#` at the start of the line) the offending settings and so on.

Comment: Just running `mysql` would troubleshoot it? in my computer it just says that can't connect to mysql through socket.

Answer (score 0):

I googled a lot, but none of the answers worked for me. I ended up with installing MySQL 5.6 ;(. Ubuntu 16.04 comes with MySQL 5.7 by default. If you don't have a specific reason to use 5.7, staying with 5.6 might be a time saving option.

```
apt-get purge mysql-*
rm -fr /var/lib/mysql*
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe'
apt-get update
apt install mysql-server-5.6
```

Comment: Adding repositories of other Ubuntu releases (without proper Apt rules in place) is begging for trouble. -1