# Upgrade to mysql-server 5.7.20 InnoDB problem

Tags: server, upgrade, mysql

it seems that mysql has been upgraded today to ver. 5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

I can't start the mysql server since because of InnoDB:
When I set

```
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:2M:autoextend
```

(which I found out should be the correct size) I get the error

```
[ERROR] InnoDB: Tablespace size must be at least 5 MB
```

When I set it to

```
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:5M:autoextend
```

I get the error

```
InnoDB: The Auto-extending innodb_system data file './ibdata1' is of a different size 128 pages (rounded down to MB) than specified in the .cnf file: initial 320 pages, max 0 (relevant if non-zero) pages!
```

Do I miss something? How do I get it fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working now with help from this thread: [MySQL not working after upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/777845/mysql-not-working-after-upgrade-from-14-04-to-16-04?rq=1)

I had to remove these two lines  from my.cnf

```
key_buffer_size = 16M
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP
```